# Two transactions reverted but never refunded?

Tags: uniswap

new at crypto, I attempted two swaps on Uniswap and both failed and stated they were being reverted here but I still haven't received the funds 8 hours later.

Any ideas on what might have happened?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2f432a22f0b91ea4a0f2e11e540f838a08aaad107168a6640a0d643fe2592426
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2429aa10da412db774d483adc021ac1a8de85efef19d0912e86f1ad1ccc2e9bb

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: The ethers never leave your wallet because the transaction reverted. If the wallet doesn't show correct values the check the balance with a different wallet or on a block explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, most likely the gas price you used was to low, I have seen gas prices were around 74Gwei trhough the day, so your transaction wasn't included because of the 42 Gwei gas price , probably.

Uniswap contracts prevent any trading if transactions are very old, and this is what happened to you:

```
abstract contract PeripheryValidation is BlockTimestamp {
    modifier checkDeadline(uint256 deadline) {
        require(_blockTimestamp() <= deadline, 'Transaction too old');
        _;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/base/PeripheryValidation.sol

No funds will be returned since the transaction was cancelled. Try tomorrow morning 6 o'clock NY time is the best time to place transactions due to low gas fees

Comment: Thanks for help! Is there any way to get the Eth back then?